# What is the suitable woo-commerce API to create order with attribution

Tags: api, woocommerce

I'm trying to create order through Woo-commerce API, the product is there with all its selected attributes' values.
I looked at the order create API and I saw nothing there for setting the values of the selected attributes.
Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, that I should've used the corresponding **variation_id** that matches the selected values of the product's attributes.